# AD DS forward to Azure Private DNS Zone

Tags: azure, entra-id, azure-dns

Hi does anyone know how to forward traffic to a Azure private zone dns from a custom ad DS.

We can’t use the new dns forwarder solution as it’s still in preview :(

If we add a forwarder for 168.63.129.16 (azure dns) will that forward to our private zone or do we need to create a forwarder in our dns for private zone?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this from a DNS server VM in an Azure VNET.  That IP address is not accessible outside of the VNET.

From there, add a conditional forwarder for the relevant private link domain to that IP.

The Azure DNS forwarder is essentially doing the same thing but with more features and without you having to maintain the server itself.